# Show did if nothing is selected in <select>

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript, can you show a div if NOTHING is selected in a  dropdown?.. And if anything is selected, hide the div. I'm seeing all these posts that if something selected, they want to show a div.. I want to do the opposite.

This is what I had when I selected it.. I want to do where it finds the id or name where it is selected.. Not the value..

```
 <select onchange="selectOther(this);">
  <option value="@" id="otherSelected" name="other">Other</option> 
 </select>

 <div id="result">Cool</div>

 function selectOther(that) {
  if (that.value == '@') { 
   document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block'; 
  } 
  else {  
   document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none'; 
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the default state of the div?

Comment: can you share code which you have tried

Comment: So add change event and show/hide the element

Comment: listen to the select menu's `change` event, then check if it has a `val` or not

Comment: Ya'll didn't have to down vote it.. Jerk.

Comment: It was just a question.. I already knew how to do it to show.. I was wondering if there was a possible way to hide.. That's all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
dropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (!(this.value)) {
        div.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="myDropdown">
  <option selected></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv">
  VISIBLE/HIDDEN
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Comment: glad to help :).